# My search engine shows no errors yet it displays no results

Tags: php, mysql

I want to make a search engine. I got this following code. The code is written to trim out spaces, count rows and amount of matching results and also a bit sql injection proof. All these attributes work but the search itself shows no results. Neither do I get an error report. I have been reviewing this code for some time now and I just can't find what is going wrong.
I know this is mysql and deprecated but I figured it should still work.
Is the reason why it's not working because Mysql is deprecated or can you find a mistake I have made?
Hopefully my question is clear enough.

the Index:

```
<form action = "" method="POST">
    <p>
        <input type="Text" name="keywords" /> <input type="submit" value="Search" />
    </p>
</form>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['keywords'])) {
    $keywords = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities(trim($_POST['keywords'])));

    $errors = array();

    if (empty($keywords)) {
        $errors[] = 'Please enter a search term';
    } else if (strlen($keywords)<3) {
        $errors[] = 'Your search term must be three or more characters';
    } else if (search_results($keywords) === false) {
        $errors[] = 'Your search for '. $keywords .' returned no results';
    }

    if (empty($errors)) {

        echo '<p>Your search for <strong>', $keywords ,'</strong> returned <strong> </strong> results</p>';
    foreach($results as $result) {
            echo '<p> <strong>', $result['Categorie'],' <br> ', $result['SerieNummer'] ,' <br> ', $result['MacAdress'] ,'</a> </p>';
        }

    } else {
      foreach($errors as $error) {
      echo $error, '</br>';
    }

}
}
?>
```

The config:

```
<?php
include 'db.inc.php';


function search_results($keywords) {
    $returned_results = array();
    $where = "";

    $keywords = preg_split('/[\s]+/', $keywords);
    $total_keywords = count($keywords);

    foreach($keywords as $key=>$keyword) {
        $where .= "`keywords` LIKE '%$keyword%'";
      if ($key != ($total_keywords -1)) {
        $where .= " AND ";
      }
    }
    $results = "SELECT `calleridname`, LEFT(`calleridnum`, 70) as `calleridnum`, `callapiid` FROM `callflow` WHERE $where";
    $results_num =  ($results = mysql_query($results)) ? mysql_num_rows($results): 0;

    if ($results_num === 0) {
        return false;
    } else {

        while ($results_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($results)) {
            $returned_results[] = array(
                            `calleridname` => $results_row['calleridname'],
                            `calleridnum` => $results_row['calleridnum'],
                            `callapiid` => $results_row['callapiid'],
            );
        }

        return $returned_results;

    }

    }


?>
```

Comment: Use `echo` to output your generated SQL query (from `search_results`) and try to run it in PHPMyAdmin or similar database tool. This will show you if theres problem with query (more possible in case you have no error reported) or PHP code.

Comment: I wonder where you think the preventing of SQL injections is done..  $where .= "`keywords` LIKE '%$keyword%'";
That code breaks as soon as a user inserts a single quote in the form. For MySQL, you might want to use the mysql_real_escape_string() function for a little bit of prevention against SQL injections.

Comment: `mysql_*` functions are deprecated, try the safer MySQLi or PDO instead. Also, you have invalid XHTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by that you used single quotes here:

```
'%$keyword%'
```

in your SQL query. Change it to `"%$keyword%"` and it will work!

Additionally
In this line, remove the last `,`

```
`callapiid` => $results_row['callapiid'],
```

Comment: It seems this Indeed makes a difference only now I get this error:-

 Warning: Division by zero in C:\wamp\www\Andere PHP projectjes\func.inc.php on line 13 -:

this error shows up as a result of my search. Any idea what the issue is?

Comment: You divide by zero in func.inc.php, that's pretty obvious. Check the variable for 0.